# Why is the break statement not exiting my while loop?

Tags: python

Normally, the `break` statement should exit my `while` loop. If I enter `'Stop'`, instead of exiting the loop, I just get asked for input again. What am I doing wrong?
My goal is it to write a program which asks the user if a student is present or if not. I had a problem with stopping my little program when I am typing in 'Stop' into my input so I searched the internet and found things like sys.Exit(0) or quit but all this did not work so I put my thing into a `while` loop so I can use `break` to stop whenever I want to stop my code but I think I muddled myself...

```
while True:
    #Schüler1
    while True:
        Schüler1 = input("Ist Schüler1 da?")
        if Schüler1 == 'Stop':
            break
        elif Schüler1 == 'Ja':
            s1 = 1
        elif Schüler1 == 'Nein':
            s1 = 0
        else:
            print("Bitte Ja, Nein oder Stop eingeben!")

        Schüler2 = input("Ist Schüler2 da?")
        if Schüler2 == 'Stop':
            print("Programm wird beendet...")
            break
        elif Schüler2 == 'Ja':
            s2 = 1
        elif Schüler2 == 'Nein':
            s2 = 0
        else:
            print("Bitte Ja, Nein oder Stop eingeben!")
    #Ausgabe
    #Kein Schüler
        if s1 + s2 == 0:
            print ("Es sind heute keine Schüler anwesend.")
        #1 Schüler
        elif s1 + s2 == 1:
            print ("Es ist heute ein Schüler anwesend.")

        #Mehr als 1 Schüler
        elif s1 + s2 > 1:
            print ("Es sind heute " + str(s1) + str(s2) + " Schüler anwesend.")
```

Comment: For more information please see https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577

Comment: add `continue` after `print("Bitte Ja, Nein oder Stop eingeben!")`  ojn same indention level to start over asking for pupil1. Unindent `if s1 + s2 == 0:` and following lines once so they get executed after you "break" from "Stop"

Comment: In the code given, you *do* break out of the inner loop, but then it just immediately starts up again as the only statement in the *outer* loop.

Comment: This question is very clear, as is the problem. You have a loop in a loop, when you break you loop. Solution remove one of the `while True:`s.